# JavaScript how to strip/remove a char from string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm looking on how to remove a char from a string for example let's say i have "#22UP0G0YU" i want it to remove the # from it how would i do? I also have a small little other question too about how to make string upper case as well thanks in advance.

Comment: `"#22UP0G0YU".slice(1)` if`#` is always first character and `"#22UP0G0YU".toUpperCase()` for uppercase.

Comment: Do you always want to remove the first char? or # or could it be any char anywhere within the string?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and code

Answer (score -1):

To remove a specific char I normally use replace, also good for a set of chars:

```
var str = '#22UP0G0YU';
var newString = str.replace('#', ''); // result: '22UP0G0YU'
```

To Uppercase, just use .toUpperCase();

```
var str = '#22UP0G0yu';
var newString = str.replace('#', '').toUpperCase(); // result: '22UP0G0YU'
```

Comment: The result of replace is being ignored.  Edit your answer: `str = str.replace('#', '');`

Comment: I did that but it didn't really edit the var so i had to assign the replace in another variable. Thx anyway, I'm still looking for how 2 make string uppercase

Comment: @FreeTNT Yeah I should have stated that it needst to be added to the variable, i've updated it, and added the upper case help you needed.